# Can't get bundling and minification to work on MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I'm trying to bundle and minify my css and js files with a MVC4 application but can't get it to work. I installed the Microsoft.Web.Optimization package making use of the package manager console.

I included the following statement in my HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/Layout/CSS" />
```

But my stylesheets are not loading. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Include the Bundling setup you are doing (Generaly in the `App_Start/BundleConfig.cs` file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've setup that bundle in `BundleConfig.cs` in your App_Start folder then you should just need to add this line in your `_layout.cshtml`:

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Styles/Layout/CSS")
```

The path of the bundle should be the same as in the `BundleConfig.cs` file

If you don't have a BundleConfig.cs file then the easiest thing to do is create a new MVC application project (internet application template) and follow the example there.

Comment: You should be using virtual paths for bundles (`~/Styles/Layout/CSS`) as it is agnostic to where you are rendering it.

Comment: @SimonBelanger Thanks, teach me not to just copy and paste from the question :D

Comment: We all do it sometimes (Still missing the `/` after `~`) ;)